# How to load an icon using relative path in python

Tags: python, pyqt, icons

I created a package that contains an `icon.png` inside a resource-folder:

- ../mypackage/resource/icon.png
- ../mypackage/qtprogram.py

I am now trying to access the `icon.png` in `qtprogram.py`. As they are both in `mypackage` directory, I tried using:

```
QtGui.QIcon("resource//icon.png")
```

but it did not work. However, using the full path (in relation to the main script path) did. Since this should be a shareable package, I would like to avoid using the full path. How can I do this?

Comment: Relative paths are not relative to the script, but to the *working directory*. Use the pathlib module and get the path using `Path(__file__).parent / 'resource' / 'icon.png'`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `\\` (or) `r'relative-path-to-file'` instead of `//` in `QtGui.QIcon("resource//icon.png")`.

I would use the os library.

```
import os

# If you plan to use to without PyInstaller
icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r'resources\icon.png') 

# If you plan to use to pyinstaller
icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), r'resources\icon.png')
```

Comment: Qt internally uses Unix separators (`/`), so using backslash separators is actually *not* a good idea especially for portability. Also, using the SL pathlib module is now the common suggested practice instead of legacy os.path.